# Ndk-cygwin path specific issues

Tags: android, path, cygwin, native, android-ndk

Amusing windows xp, cygwin & ndk for my project. I mapped all path in the cygwin.batch file. I am trying to compile hello-jni by cygwin.

**Contents of cygwin.bat**

@echo off

```
F:
chdir F:\Cygwin\bin

bash --login -i

set IS_UNIX=

set DEV_ROOT=E:/android/android-ndk-r5b/samples/hello-jni

set JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.5.0_13

set CLASSPATH=d:/work_code/android/BlueInput/obj

set PATH=E:/android/android-sdk-windows/tools;E:/android/android-ndk-r5b

set ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/cygdrive/e/android/android-ndk-r5b

set NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/cygdrive/e/android/android-ndk-r5b/samples/hello-jni
```

**on executing the command ./ndk-build, am getting the error...**

```
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory!

Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.

cygdrive\e\android\android-ndk-r5b\build\core\build-local.mk:"Android NDK aborting"
```

Comment: hi all, i solved it. in cygwin i exported the path & compiled it perfectly.    NDK_PROJECT_PATH="path of the project"      then, export=NDK_PROJECT_PATH  then, i compiled it directly by ./ndk-build from the cygwin shell.

Comment: I had the same issue and I solved using this blog post: http://android-jotting.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-ndk-error-reference-for-noob.html

Comment: this has done the trick.

Comment: Any chance you can provide more details? How do you export in cygwin?

Comment: in command line,enter the following command $NDK_PROJECT_PATH="enter the path here", then press enter & then type the command $export NDK_PROJECT_PATH.

Comment: I highly suggest that you just bite the bullet and work on a Unix-like OS. Dual booting something like Ubuntu is dead easy and is very low risk. Of course, if you can't do this for some reason, ignore me.

Answer (score 1):

The parent folder should be "jni" and then inside your Android.mk

Answer (score 0):

Trigger ndk-build script from your project's jni folder (the folder where Android.mk is located and your c/c++ files) and not from the android-ndk directory.