# cygwin cannot find android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin

Hi I'm following an android tutorial on ndk (Hello-jni) and I am trying to run the following command within cygwin

```
        android update project -p . -s
```

but I get the following message:

```
      -bash: android: command not found
```

I am new at this and I assume this is because cygwin isn't hooked up properly to Android but I do not know how to fix this. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your [path](http://pielot.org/2010/12/09/using-cygwin-with-the-android-ndk-on-windows/), so that cygwin knows where to find the android program.

In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025986/ndk-cygwin-path-specific-issues), see the line that says,

> set PATH=E:/android/android-sdk-windows/tools;E:/android/android-ndk-r5b

Comment: Thanks Yusuf but I have actually seen this before and tried going through it but it is a little complex and I didnt quite understand

Comment: I added the specific line you need to the answer.

Comment: It says android_ndk_r5b is a directory?

Comment: the address is for wherever you installed Android.  it might be android_sdk_version instead of android_ndk_version, but yeah.

Comment: Your android program may also be in E:/android/android-sdk-windows/tools, but probably isn't. See where that program is installed and set PATH to point to that.

Answer (score 0):

SET:

```
export ANT_HOME=`cygpath –u “$ANT_HOME”`
export JAVA_HOME=`cygpath –u “$JAVA_HOME”`
export ANDROID_SDK=`cygpath –u “$ANDROID_SDK”`
export ANDROID_NDK=`cygpath –u “$ANDROID_NDK”`
```

in your .bash_profile in cygwin_path\home{username}